# Pandas string addition across columns

Tags: python, pandas

This is perfectly legal in Python:

```
In [1]: 'abc' + 'def'
Out[1]: 'abcdef'
```

If I have an all text Pandas DataFrame, like the example below:

```
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([list('abcd'), list('efgh'), list('ijkl')],
                          columns=['C1','C2','C3','C4'])
        df.loc[[0,2], ['C2', 'C3']] = np.nan
        df
Out[2]:     C1  C2  C3  C4
        0   a   NaN NaN d
        1   e   f   g   h
        2   i   NaN NaN l
```

Is it possible to do the same with columns of the above DataFrame? Something like:

```
In [3]: df.apply(+, axis=1) # Or
        df.sum(axis=1)
```

Note that both of the statements above don't work. Using `.str.cat()` in a loop is easy, but I am looking for something better.

---

Expected output is:

```
Out[3]:    C
        0  ad
        1  efgh
        2  il
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do

```
df.fillna('').sum(axis=1)
```

Of course, this assumes that your dataframe is made up only of strings and NaNs.

Comment: I assume my dataframe is made up of only strings and `NaN`s, I hope it is correct! :-P

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**
*`stack`*

I wanted to add it for demonstration.  We don't have to accept the rectangular nature of the dataframe and use `stack`.  When we do, `stack` drops `nan` by default.  Leaving us with a vector of strings and a `pd.MultiIndex`.  We can `groupby` the first level of this `pd.MultiIndex` (which used to be row indices) and perform summation:

```
df.stack().groupby(level=0).sum()

0      ad
1    efgh
2      il
dtype: object
```

---

**Option2**
*Use Masked Arrays [`np.ma.masked_array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html)*
I was motivated by @jezrael to post a faster solution (-:

```
pd.Series(
    np.ma.masked_array(
        df.values,
        df.isnull().values,
    ).filled('').sum(1),
    df.index
)

0      ad
1    efgh
2      il
dtype: object
```

---

**Timing**

```
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

%%timeit
pd.Series(
    np.ma.masked_array(
        df.values,
        df.isnull().values,
        fill_value=''
    ).filled('').sum(1),
    df.index
)

1000 loops, best of 3: 860 µs per loop

%timeit (pd.Series(df.fillna('').values.sum(axis=1), index=df.index))

1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop
```

Comment: Alternate approaches are always welcome, my friend. We cannot guarantee one size fits all.

Comment: @Kartik I couldn't agree more (-:

Answer (score 2):

A bit faster solution is convert to numpy array by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and then [`numpy.sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html):

```
#[3000 rows x 4 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)
#print (df)

In [49]: %timeit (df.fillna('').sum(axis=1))
100 loops, best of 3: 4.08 ms per loop

In [50]: %timeit (pd.Series(df.fillna('').values.sum(axis=1), index=df.index))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.49 ms per loop

In [51]: %timeit (pd.Series(np.sum(df.fillna('').values, axis=1), index=df.index))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: hmmm, nice one.